# IntelliJ git ignore template

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ for quite a few years now (since 6 I think@2007) and I love it. 
In the recent years with the maven/gradle project we have stopped committing the IntelliJ project specific files of IntelliJ (the .idea folder and the .iml files).

This means though that when I checkout a project (from git for example) I get something like this:
[image: Intellij Project files]

And then I have to do 2 git ignores:

1. To ignore the .idea folder

[image]

2. To ignore all the files with the .iml extension

So my question is this:
Is there a template to set this thing up so that every time I checkout a project these ignore settings will exist by default?

[EDIT]
I have found the following 2:

1. This plugin that generates .gitignore files for many cases including Jetbrains projects (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=phpStorm)
2. This website that gives you the .gitignore (is the same template for Jetbrains/IntelliJ) for many cases including Jetbrains pojects (https://www.gitignore.io/)

But I find the IntelliJ method better than going to file system and adding the file myself. Also the IntelliJ method marks them as ignored while the addition to the .gitignore list does not mark them at all. It just shows them as unmodified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so after using the plugin [.gitignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=phpStorm) I find that this is the closest I get to what I need. Its not EXACTLY what I need, which is to not have to configure anything and git would ignore the files/dirs that I want, but with a couple of clicks I have the configuration ready with .idea folder and .iml files ignored